# computing the area of an ellipse $x^2-2xy+2y^2+4y=8$ using a specified change of variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am trying to calculate the area of an enclosed ellipse $x^2-2xy+2y^2+4y=8$ as an integral in the variables $u=x-y$ and $v=y+2$.  To be completely honest I am at a loss for ideas here I am not sure where to begin. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried grouping to make squared terms?  For example $(x-y)^2$.

Comment: I thought that is what I had to do but I am having trouble getting the method of grouping even with anurags answer below im trying to figure the process to get there so I understand for my test

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

With $u=x-y$ and $v=y+2$ you get 
\begin{align*}
x^2-2xy+2y^2+4y & =8\\
(x-y)^2+(y+2)^2 & =12\\
u^2+v^2 & =12.
\end{align*}
Now compute the Jacobian etc.. to get the volume.

Comment: how do you know to factor it to (x-y)^2 and (y+2)^2.  Like how do you see those terms inside the polynomial. Any tips?

Comment: and shouldn't you add 4 to both sides or it won't factor into that correctly?